# Set tabline to display current working directory for each tabpage?

Tags: vim

I am using vim to separate each of my projects into different tabs. Within each of these tabs, I have changed the directory so that the current working directory (as returned by `getcwd()`) for each tab is the root filepath of the project.

Instead of displaying the filepath of the currently activated window for each tab, I would like `tabline` to display the working directory for each tab. This way if I want to navigate to the "ProjectB" tab, I can just click on the tab that shows the working directory of ProjectB. This way my tabs look like...

[1 /path/to/projecta] [2 /path/to/projectb] [3 /path/to/projectc]

...instead of showing ambiguous filenames (that are often repeated between projects using similar filenaming conventions) such as...

[1 index.html] [2 styles.css] [3 App.rb]

Answer (score 2):

See `:h setting-tabline`

---

The 'tabline' option allows you to define your preferred way to tab pages
labels.  This isn't easy, thus an example will be given here.

For basics see the 'statusline' option.  The same items can be used in the
'tabline' option.  Additionally, the |tabpagebuflist()|, |tabpagenr()| and
|tabpagewinnr()| functions are useful.

Since the number of tab labels will vary, you need to use an expression for
the whole option.  Something like:

```
:set tabline=%!MyTabLine()
```

Then define the MyTabLine() function to list all the tab pages labels.  A
convenient method is to split it in two parts:  First go over all the tab
pages and define labels for them.  Then get the label for each tab page.

```
function MyTabLine()
  let s = ''
  for i in range(tabpagenr('$'))
    " select the highlighting
    if i + 1 == tabpagenr()
      let s .= '%#TabLineSel#'
    else
      let s .= '%#TabLine#'
    endif

    " set the tab page number (for mouse clicks)
    let s .= '%' . (i + 1) . 'T'

    " the label is made by MyTabLabel()
    let s .= ' %{MyTabLabel(' . (i + 1) . ')} '
  endfor

  " after the last tab fill with TabLineFill and reset tab page nr
  let s .= '%#TabLineFill#%T'

  " right-align the label to close the current tab page
  if tabpagenr('$') > 1
    let s .= '%=%#TabLine#%999Xclose'
  endif

  return s
endfunction
```

Now the MyTabLabel() function is called for each tab page to get its label. >

```
function MyTabLabel(n)
  let buflist = tabpagebuflist(a:n)
  let winnr = tabpagewinnr(a:n)
  return bufname(buflist[winnr - 1])
endfunction
```

This is just a simplistic example that results in a tab pages line that
resembles the default, but without adding a + for a modified buffer or
truncating the names.  You will want to reduce the width of labels in a
clever way when there is not enough room.  Check the 'columns' option for the
space available.

---

In your case you could store the working directory for each tab in a list and set the tab label to the corresponding list element (using the MyTabLine function from above aswell).

```
let twds = ['one', 'two']
function! MyTabLabel(n)
    return get(g:twds, a:n - 1, '[no name]')
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using MacVim so I actually want to set the GuiLine. This works for me:

```
    function! GuiTabLabel()
      let tab_num = tabpagenr()
      let win_num = tabpagewinnr(tab_num)
      return getcwd(win_num, tab_num)
    endfunction

    set guitablabel=%{GuiTabLabel()}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for Lua and Neovim. This code works in the Lua config `init.lua`.

```
-- ## Tabline, defines how tabpages title looks like
-- For convenience of cross-probjects development, show project names directly.
function MyTabLine()
    local tabline = ""
    for index = 1, vim.fn.tabpagenr('$') do
        -- Select the highlighting for the current tabpage.
        if index == vim.fn.tabpagenr() then
            tabline = tabline .. '%#TabLineSel#'
        else
            tabline = tabline .. '%#TabLine#'
        end

        local win_num = vim.fn.tabpagewinnr(index)
        local working_directory = vim.fn.getcwd(win_num, index)
        local project_name = vim.fn.fnamemodify(working_directory, ":t")
        tabline = tabline .. " " .. project_name .. " "
    end

    return tabline
end
vim.go.tabline = "%!v:lua.MyTabLine()"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved if it said that it's a solution for Neovim only. I guess that most people familiar with the Vim ecosystem know it but one can never be sure.